# What does the hashtag #FaceABaba mean

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, société

I follow a few French-language "tweeters". Just recently, I have noticed the hashtag `#FaceABaba` appearing with some frequency. I've done online searches, but have been unable to find the "meaning" or significance of this hashtag. Can someone shed light on the origin of this?

Comment: https://www.lepoint.fr/medias/lancement-de-face-a-baba-c8-cyril-hanouna-recoit-eric-zemmour-23-11-2021-2453545_260.php

Comment: A want-to-be Trump on a want-to-be Fox News... https://www.huffingtonpost.fr/entry/face-a-baba-avec-zemmour-et-hanouna-deux-facettes-du-systeme-de-bollore_fr_61b9e555e4b03f82dd585296

Comment: Please give more context and show what meanings you have found that you don't understand.

Comment: @livresque: I found no meanings online - that is why I asked here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*Face à Baba*" (In front of "Baba") is the name of a new TV Talk Show / Politainment that was launched today on the C8 channel. Its presenter is Cyril Hanouna whose nickname is *Baba* since he was a kid.

Today's guest was Eric Zemmour, a want to be Donald Trump while the TV channel certainly dreams to become a French Fox News.